# Viewshed Analysis With GDAL

Tags: gdal, viewshed

I am looking to perform a simple (one observer location) viewshed analysis on a standard DEM using GDAL (either python or .NET bindings).

I have searched, but haven't found any readily available implementation.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is GRASS an acceptable candidate for your solution?  It typically includes tools for these things: r.los and r.viewshed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've used python scripts to run both the *r.los* and *r.viewshed* grass commands that Peter mentioned.

The advantage  with *r.los* is that it works straight out-of-the-box with grass6, but is slightly slower to run over large raster DEMs.  *r.viewshed* is a bit of a pain to get running, but is a vast speed improvement on very large rasters.  See if the times for your DEM are acceptable using *r.los*, then give *r.viewshed* a go if it's taking too long.  Here's a quick python example using grass64 *r.viewshed*, but you'll need to get the python grass bindings working first (see http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Python).

```
import grass.script as grass

grass.run_command('r.viewshed',
        input='standard.dem',
        output='viewshed',
        coordinate=[observer_x, observer_y],
        obs_elev=1.75,
        tgt_elev=0.0,
        memory=4098,
        overwrite=True,
        quiet=True
)
```

with a better description of the parameters available at http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/html_grass70/r.viewshed.html

Answer (score 1):

There is also [SAGA-GIS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/) which provides visibility analysis. It has Python bindings.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a QGIS plugin that does this. I can not remember the name of the plugin at the moment, it works, but I find it a little slow.

Comment: It's been a while since you sort of answered this question without a real answer?  Do you have an update or maybe just delete the answer?

Comment: Thank you for the reminder Ryan, and sorry for forgetting.  Here is a link to a description about the plugin.  I did a search for the plugin in for QGIS 1.8.0 and it is not coming up in the Plugin Search.  

     http://madchuckle.blogspot.ca/2010/05/effects-of-precision-in-viewshed.html

Comment: Here is another description of the plugin

     http://madchuckle.blogspot.ca/2010/10/visibility-analysis-plugin-vap-for-qgis.html