# How to calculate Viewshed from a DEM file using a command line tool?

Tags: gdal, dem, viewshed

I need to take a polygon that show the viewshed given a point in a DEM file to ask the question: "What can I see from here to X kilometers ? "

I already read this [Performing viewshed analysis with Dutch AHN files in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153198/performing-viewshed-analysis-with-dutch-ahn-files-in-qgis)

but I need to calculate it using a command line tool like GDAL in a headless Linux environment.

I must give a DEM file, a coordinate (obviously it must fall into the DEM bounding box) and expect to receive a polygon geometry containing the viewshed area.

Is such thing possible to do?

EDIT:

Sorry guys... I need to take a look in some options. Seems I was too fast to ask.

[Viewshed Analysis With GDAL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29414/viewshed-analysis-with-gdal):
I down't know if I can install GRASS in my server just for this...

https://github.com/jonnyhuck/Viewshed: GREAT! Will give a look...

https://github.com/thingless/viewshed : OPS! Site offline but the code is still there...